# get data from flat file and insert data into database in Java

Tags: java

I open new question about the extract data and insert to database. I change and modified the code become like this but still not working.

Flat file:

```
DT|00000001|TMDWH|UNIFI|00380520160|MAH SIEW YIN|11  |JALAN PP 2/8|TAMAN PUTRA PRIMA|PUCHONG|SELANGOR|47100|MALAYSIA|801110-14-5498||||||VOBB||A||11|JALAN PP 2/8|||TAMAN PUTRA PRIMA

DT|00000002|TMDWH|UNIFI|00322012091|JUNITA BINTI JAMAL|6 10 KONDOMINIUM FAJARIA|JALAN PANTAI BARU|KUALA LUMPUR|KUALA LUMPUR|WILAYAH PERSEKUTUAN|59200|MALAYSIA|800129-09-5078||||||VOBB||A|||JALAN PANTAI BARU|6|KONDOMINIUM FAJARIA|KUALA LUMPUR
```

Program:

```
public void massageData(String tmp) {
    String[] fields = tmp.replace("\"", " ")
                         .replace("\'","\'\'")
                         .trim()
                         .split("\\s*\\|\\s*");

Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;

String actualMSISDN = parseMSISDN(fields[5]);

    if (actualMSISDN.length() > 8) {
        String [] aNo = getAreaCode(actualMSISDN).split("\\|");
        field[0] = getiCtr(parseMSISDN(fields[5]));

        String stateCode = lookupStateCode(State);
        String  sQuery = "insert into DATA_999 ( ,RecordType,RecordNumber,SourceSystemApplicationId,TargetApplicationId,TelNo,Name,HouseNo,StreetName,AppartmentSuite,TownCity,State,PostalCode,Country,NewIC,OldIC,PassportNo,BRN,LatitudeDecimal,LongitudeDecimal,ServiceType,IndicatorType,CreateDate,Filler,Cr_Nl,HouseNo_New,LotNo_New,StreetName_New,AptNo_New,BuildingName_New,LowIDRange,HighIDRange,SectionName) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        try {   
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sQuery);

            int col = 0;
            for (String field : fields) {
                stmt.setString(++col, field); // Note: SQL API is 1-based (not zero-based)
            }

            int dbStat = stmt.executeUpdate();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException s){
            logger.error(s.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            try {if (stmt != null) stmt.close();} catch (SQLException e) {}
            try {if (conn != null) conn.close();} catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe in your questions how the fields of each row map to the columns in the database table?

Comment: Can you send the thrown exception? The DDL for `DATA_999` table is appreciated, too.

Comment: Please read the FAQ  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Dear mR_frOg, why I need to read faq?..I already read that..:P

Comment: Dear Tichodroma, the table is like this:-

ID
RecordType
RecordNumber 
and so on..I want to extract data from flat file and insert into database..could you please help me?

Comment: Dear Frm, No exception thrown, the code was successfully compiled!..but the data is not store into table DATA_999, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You're actually trying to insert double the amount of fields in 1 row. Also you seem to have an error in your sql query: the first field is absent and there's only a comma there.

It also seems to me that you're not doing anything yourself: you use the advice people give you, change your code and if it doesn't work you create a new question.

Comment: Dear Kurt Du Bois, I already change it, but still cannot work..Anymore idea?